# loading nested JSON store of the same type

Tags: javascript, extjs

I've found a lot of examples of how to load nested JSON stores when the children are a different model type, but I haven't found any that show you how to do the same thing if all of the children are of the same type.  I have JSON data like this:

```
{ 
    "ID": "id213",
    "Name": "ItemName",
    "ChildElements": [
       {
           "ID": "id321",
           "Name": "ItemName2",
           "ChildElements": [  //contains children  ]
       },
       { 
           "ID": "id32154",
           "Name": "ItemName3",               
           "ChildElements": [  //contains children ]
       }
    ]
}
```

My model looks like this:

```
Ext.define('App.model.ElementsModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [ 
        {
            name: 'Name'
        }
    ],
    hasMany: {
        model: 'ElementsModel',
        name: 'ChildElements'
      },
    proxy: {
           type: 'ajax',
           url: 'elements.json',
           reader: {
              type: 'json',
              idProperty: 'ID'
           }
    }
});
```

and when I load the store, no child elements are being loaded.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I needed to specify a full qualified name as the association model:

```
 hasMany: {
        model: 'App.model.ElementsModel',
        name: 'ChildElements'
      },
```